# Find the absolute minimum (multivariable)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: Problem Description]

My textbook had some equation to approach this problem, but I skipped that and took a different approach.

Plugging numbers in wasn't difficult, so I used x = 2 and y = 2, to get -4 as the absolute minimum on the domain. Does this make sense, or does this basic thinking not work when there are multiple variables?

Thank you

Comment: I would highly recommend using the book's method. Although "basic thinking" might work, the purpose is for you to learn the "book's method" so that in the future, where there may be much harder problems, (answers that might not be integers, or tougher equations), the book's method will actually be easier, than thinking it out in your head.

Comment: Since there are only four choices, and $-4$ is the smallest choice, *and* you have specific choices of $x,y$ giving value $-4,$ that is the right answer given multiple choice, *unless* it is really choice (e), none of the above. To find out for sure you need two variable techniques.

Comment: I understand that basic thinking is not able to handle more complex cases. I am trying to solve it using my books equation, but I am not getting -4. I want to know if I am making a mistake applying the books equation, or if there is an error in my way of basic thinking. If the latter, could someone explain to me why I can't think like that when there are two variables? Thanks

Comment: I imagine you took partial derivatives and set them equal to $0$. The result happens to be outside our region. That leaves as candidates points on the boundary of the square, and now you have one-variable problems. We can also do it without calculus, by noting that our function is $(x-y)^2-y^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I read more into the book and it said that my eyeballing of the problem was perfectly valid. Thank you all that have replied. I will look into their equation for future more complex problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that option d) were $-3.75$ instead of $-4$. Using your logic you would then argue as follows: This is the smallest offered value, and it is indeed taken at the admissible point $(1.5,2)$. Therefore d) is correct. But of course e) would be correct in this case.

Nevertheless we can do without using calculus at all. Note that the admissible domain is a rectangle, and I can choose $x\in[1,3]$, $y\in[0,2]$ independently. For given admissible $x$ the function becomes minimal when I choose $y=2$. Therefore we have to look at the pullback
$$\phi(x):=f(x,2)=x^2-4x=(x-2)^2-4\ .$$
It is obvious that $\phi$ takes its minimum value ($=-4$) at $x=2$, which is admissible. Therefore d) is correct.